# unable to establish connection to a external ip inside docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-network

```
from zk import ZK, const

deviceInstance = ZK('*******', '****', timeout=30, password=0, force_udp=False, 
ommit_ping=False)
conn = deviceInstance.connect()
deviceInstance.enable_device()
```

When i am running this simple script using python file.py it works fine
But when i am trying to run the same script inside docker it gives me error

```
[+] Running 1/1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 ⠿ Container scriptest  Recreated                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
Attaching to scriptest
Traceback (most recent call last):
scriptest  |   File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
scriptest  |     conn = deviceInstance.connect()
scriptest  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/zk/base.py", line 367, in connect
scriptest  |     raise ZKNetworkError("can't reach device (ping %s)" % self.__address[0])
scriptest  | zk.exception.ZKNetworkError: can't reach device (ping ***.***.**.***)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /test

# Copy requirements file
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application runs on
EXPOSE 4370

CMD ["python", "script.py"]
```

This is the docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: scriptest
```